# How to get text which is visible to user in case of text overflow?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web

I have a text input where I use ellipsis to indicate that text has overflown the input size. Is there a way to see what text is visible to the user or hidden behind ellipsis?
Thank you

[image]

The use case here is that I show a list separated by commas to the user. If the list exceeds the size of the input field, I want to show something like `item1, item2,... +5 more`. To do this I need to know what text is visible to the user/hidden behind ellipsis.

Comment: you can add that text as `title`. so that `onhover` user can see that

Comment: Add Tooltip on Hover

Comment: you could use `overflow: scroll` or `overflow-x: scroll` or `oveflow-y: scroll` so that if the text is long, a user can scroll to see it

Comment: As per your new EDIT you have to use jquery/javascript to get the desired string and assign it to the input filed.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Can you please edit your answer to show how to go about it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add `title` for the same text. When user `hover` the text it will show the original text. I have given the sample for `input` and `p`

```css
.ellipse {
text-overflow:ellipsis;
width:70px;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="ellipse" title="This is the very big text">This is the very big text</p>

<input class="ellipse" title="This is the very big text" value="This is the very big text" />
```

**EDIT**

As per your new requirement you have to use JS/JQuery to achieve the desired result. I am not sure how you will get the user names in your case. I have given the sample like having array of items. Also you no need to use any CSS ellipsis property, because you really not looking for that solution. Look at the below snippet

```js
var items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'];

var orivalue = "";
var disvalue = "";

for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
 orivalue += (items.length - 1 == i) ? items[i] : items[i]+ ", ";
}
tmp = items.length - 2;
if(items.length > 2) {
  disvalue = items[0] + ", " + items[1] + ", ... +" + tmp + "more";
 }
 document.getElementById("user").value = disvalue;
 document.getElementById("user").title = orivalue;
```

```css
.ellipse {
  width:140px;
}
```

```html
<input id="user" class="ellipse" title="" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is not what I was asking for. I have edited the question with actual requirements. Please have a look.

Comment: As per your new EDIT you have to use jquery/javascript to get the desired string and assign it to the input filed.  Can you share your jquery/javascript code that you have tried??

Comment: I have tried to use the  html `value` attribute. But it returns the entire text and not what is visible to the user.

Comment: Given the logic how to get that desired output.